# Css and script gallery adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

I have a simple image gallery which contains thumbnails and when you click an image the image expands in a pop-up window.

My issue is that I can only make this function  work with one image.

I understand the body is calling

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<img class="modal-content" id="img01
```

and the script is calling

```
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
```

I just can't work out what I need to do to these elements that will allow the pop-up feature to work on all thumbnail images? Any help would be great!

Code:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.thumbnails img {
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.thumbnails img:hover {
  border: 4px solid #00ccff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnails h2 {
  color: white;
}

.thumbnails h3 {
  color: white;
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>


<body>


  <div class="thumbnails" align="center">
    <p>Text here</p>

    <div class="thumbnails" align="center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">

          <img id="myImg" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p0542jxj.jpg" alt=" 
       <h2>Text</h2> <h3>Text</h3>">


          <img id="myImg" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p0542jxj.jpg" alt=" 
       <h2>Text</h2> <h3>Text</h3>">



          <img id="myImg" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p0542jxj.jpg" alt=" 
        <h2>Text</h2> <h3>Text</h3>">



          <img id="myImg" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p0542jxj.jpg" alt=" 
        <h2>Text</h2> <h3>Text</h3>">



          <img id="myImg" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p0542jxj.jpg" alt=" 
        <h2>Text</h2> <h3>Text</h3>">


          <!-- The Modal -->
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01" style="height:400px;" width="720px;">
            <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>

        </div><br/></div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems you are calling same id on click, so it will trigger same image

Comment: To add to the above comment a little further, it will target the _first_ image with the given ID (all IDs in HTML *should be unique*). I wouldn't recommend using classes for this (looks messy poluting the class tree with arbitrary names) - have a look at data attributes. Something like `data-image-id='image1'` would make for better semantics.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is very helpful, even the mention of classes instead of id. 
But yes I will look into data attributes, it would be good to keep the code as uncluttered as possible. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the id which is unique. try using classes.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I will try classes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using same id for all the images, if yes it wont work because ids are unique .you cant assign same id for different elements

Comment: That is the case at the moment and now I understand why that won't work. Thank you for pointing that out.